# Why is "improve this question / answer" shown to anonymous users instead of "edit"?

Tags: discussion, edits

If I browse a site as an anonymous user, instead of "edit" I see: "improve this question / answer".

> [image]

I don't get it, are anonymous users considered to be kinda dumb and don't understand "edit"?

Why to reword this action?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They can't edit. They can only suggest edits.

And there is no way to tell, when one is anonymous that the suggested edit is in a queue to be approved or rejected. Which is different to logged in users who get a little notice that explains exactly that on the post they just suggested an edit on.

It is also more of a call to action than an edit link - it invites them to do more than just edit the post - to improve it. A bit more of an invitation to participate positively in the site.

Comment: Also worth noting that those are the only two options an anonymous user can ever see, so there's no reason to compress it into a tiny edit button. A registered user, when logged in, can see anywhere from 2 to 7 (?) options down in that list depending on their privileges, so a huge "improve this post" button is very space consuming.

Comment: Heh, I didn't think that anonymous users have no ability to find their suggested edit (or, at least, it is difficult). And about improving: I thought that everyone is supposed to improve a post by editing (and participate positively), not just anonymous users :)

Comment: @ani Good point, why not to uncompress "share" then? "share a link to this question". Now those options look worthily :D And, as for me, I'd like names of actions to be as short as possible. So it could be just "improve" (if not "edit").

Comment: @nicael `share` is well understandable (from all social networks), and people can hardly do any damage by clicking it, after all. However, editing other people's posts is not so common, so it makes sense to emphasize the purpose of the button.

Comment: Don't forget that anonymous visitors probably haven't 'bought in' to the way the site works,  that is everyone is free to edit.

Comment: All users <3k rep can only make "suggested edits". 2.5k is a long way from a user not logged in.