# Why does the edit button say 'improve this question/answer' when logged out but 'edit' when logged in?

Tags: discussion, edits

Why, when I am logged out, does the button say “improve this question” or “improve this answer”, but when I am logged in it says “edit”?

I have ~450 reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think more than anything it's about emphasising "improve" to people new to the site, as editing isn't common in (eg) forums.

---

I voted to close as possible duplicate of [Why is "improve this question / answer" shown to anonymous users instead of "edit"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246755/why-is-improve-this-question-answer-shown-to-anonymous-users-instead-of-edi) as it's the same question, although not sure I agree entirely with the current answer.

It states:

> They [non logged in users] can't edit. They can only suggest edits.

But that is true of all users until 2k rep, they are all "suggested edits".

I expect there to be system differences between non-logged in and <3k rep, but that doesn't fully explain the reason to have different wording.

Comment: I think that you get the editing privilege for posts at 2k rep on non beta sites, and 500 on betas.

Comment: The limit is (usually) 2,000, not 3,000.

Comment: Thanks Peter, fixed the typo