# Should we prevent "Improve this Question" from appearing when a user has 200 reputation on another site?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, edits, suggested-edits, association-bonus

When a user gains 200 reputation on any site, the association bonus applies as soon as they join the site.  However before they join, they are treated as a 1 rep user.  This means that "Improve this Question" appears instead of "Edit".

This doesn't make sense for several reasons:

- While this may be good for new users, users with 200 rep in any site have sufficient experience that they should be able to know what "Edit" means.
- This may confuse users, as they are used to "Edit" and not "Improve this Question"
- You are still part of the SE community, and have proven yourself capable on one site

Comment: Why should they? If they haven't joined yet then they are still an anonymous user on that particular site and should be treated as such. They also cannot vote or use any other privileges until they've created a profile there.

Comment: @animuson They still proved an understanding of SE and know what "Edit" means.

Comment: That's not really relevant. "Improve this post" is shown to anonymous users and "Edit" is shown to logged-in users. It has nothing to do with your reputation. The simple solution is to create a profile there, and seeing the Improve text is a great emphasis that you haven't yet done that and would be suggesting an anonymous edit.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246755/why-is-improve-this-question-answer-shown-to-anonymous-users-instead-of-edi) [posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312661/why-does-the-edit-button-say-improve-this-question-answer-when-logged-out-but?noredirect=1&lq=1).  The answer on the latter question explains it pretty well, I think.

Comment: @Ollie I disagree, the latter explains why users not signed see that, but not why when you haven't joined a community that shows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Missing the edit button is a very useful prompt and warning that any edit you make will not be attributed to your profile, but to the [Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/369802). In other words: It is the first and most obvious warning sign that the suggested edit you're about to make won't earn you any reputation when approved.

Right now, when I encounter something I'd like to edit, and it says 'Improve this Question/Answer', I know I'm either not logged in, or haven't made a profile on that site yet. If that button were to say 'Edit' instead, I'd have to rely on the following message:

[image]

Which is not so obviously different from the usual message I get when trying to edit something on a site where I do have a profile, just no editing privileges:

[image]

[Banner blindness is a real thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banner_blindness). For experienced users, they know that suggesting an edit will give a yellow banner thingy, no way they're going to take the time to read that. They know the message, they've seen it countless times, they'll be *blind to that banner*.

So yeah, keep the different button instead. It's a way more useful sign that you haven't joined the community yet and will be missing out on the reward for improving the post if you don't create a profile first.