# Add a tooltip for "Improve this question/answer"

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, tooltips, anonymous

When logged out/anonymous, the "Edit" link [is replaced by](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246755/1017231) "Improve this question/answer" (depending on post type):

> [image: "Improve this question" link]

While there is a tooltip for the regular "Edit" link ("Revise and improve this post"), there is none for the "Improve this question/answer" link. A similar tooltip would work, or perhaps something more explicit about our editing expectations. I discovered the lack of a tooltip while exploring all the other links to see what their tooltips were - this was the only one out of the list of links at a bottom of a post which lacked a tooltip.

I'm requesting a tooltip for the "Improve this question/answer" link, for consistency if nothing else. It would also make it clearer to users of other SE sites that this is just the "Edit" link under a different name.

Comment: As you mentioned, the tooltip for the "Edit" link says _"Revise and improve this post"_. The link that's shown to anonymous users already says "Improve this [post]". What else do you suggest the tooltip should say? - _"our editing expectations"_ I think that would be too long for a simple tooltip. We already have that [in the notice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c1TB.png) that's displayed to the user after they click the link.

Comment: @41686d6564 I'm not really sure what's best to go there, but it's just weird that one of these links doesn't have a tooltip when all of the others do.